# Js listen for particular width

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id=“container” style=“width: 100%”>
<div id=“block” style=“width: 50px”>
<div style=“width: 40px;”>
</div>
<div style=“width:40px;”>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need for js to listen when container’s width is more than 100px and resize div with id block to 100px.
Is it possible with js/jquery?

Comment: So add resize handler to the document and check the width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an resize event listener on the window and check the width of the div in the handler.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(e){
   var container = document.querySelector("#container");
   if(container.offsetWidth>100){
     document.querySelector("#block").style.width = "100px";
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check if it works after having some rest

Comment: @Jake No problem.

Comment: @Jake, this might be the answer to the question, but I think you should seriously consider Damani his solution. It's a lot better performance wise and what you are trying to achieve is style related. So CSS is the way to go.

Comment: @enf0rcer I asked for js solution and he didn’t explain how it’s done.

Comment: I know, but you asked the wrong question. It's like asking how you reach the McDonalds by walking when you live in a area where you need to walk for days to reach it. People will suggest better ways of reaching the same goal :)

Comment: @enf0rcer I understand what are you talking about but there is a direct question “is it possible with js/jquery?”